# Dicionário analógico online

Tags: recursos-online, recursos, thesaurus

Algumas vezes eu precisei saber qual palavra possui o significado que eu estou procurando (e tendo certeza de que existe tal palavra). Com um pouco de pesquisa, descobri que existe o que é chamado de *dicionário analógico*, isto é um dicionário temático, onde as entradas são organizadas por temas e não como uma lista alfabética de palavras.

Um exemplo de uso de um dicionário analógico, pode ser assim descrito: eu gostaria de saber qual o adjetivo para caracterizar algo da cor amarela, assim como *alvo* se refere à cor branca, *negro* à cor preta e assim por diante. Um dicionário comum não me seria de uso, pois eu não sei qual palavra estou buscando. Ao usar um *dicionário analógico* eu buscaria a categoria cores, então amarelo e lá teria as opções de palavras, entre elas o [*jalne*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/jalne) que eu buscava.

Isto posto, achei estranho quando pesquisei *dicionário analógico* no Google e não achei nenhum acessível online, apenas ofertas de livrarias que os vendem no modelo impresso. Mais estranho isto me parece quando vejo que existem diversos dicionários tradicionais ([Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Default.aspx), [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/), [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/), entre outros) online da língua portuguesa.

Minha pergunta é, alguém conhece um (bom) dicionário analógico que pode ser consultado online?

Conheci o dicionário analógico a partir [deste post de um estudioso](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/07/08/o-dicionario-analogico) da língua portuguesa que escreve em um jornal do sul do Brasil. Para uma outra definição e alguns exemplos de verbetes pode ser visto nesta resenha do [Dicionário analógico da língua portuguesa](http://terapiazero.blogspot.com.br/2010/07/dicionario-analogico-da-lingua.html), de Francisco Ferreira dos Santos Azevedo.

Comment: Você pode pesquisar por sinônimos, assim você acha outras palavras com um mesmo significado ou parecido, organizado por categorias se significado.

Comment: Puxa, conceito interessante "Dicionário Analógico". Será que pode mostrar um par de links relacionados?

Comment: Não conheço, mas se for do interesse de vocês, posso montar um.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**, o Analógico do Aulete **parece muito bom**.

### [aulete.com.br/analogico/amarelo/1/Amarelo](http://www.aulete.com.br/analogico/amarelo/1/Amarelo)

---

No artigo citado, [O Dicionário Analógico](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/07/08/o-dicionario-analogico/), por Cláudio Moreno, vemos que essa é a palavra em Português para o famoso ***Thesaurus*** que encontramos com facilidade para a língua inglesa.

Fazendo uma busca por "thesaurus da língua portuguesa" aparecem algumas opções, mas nada muito completo, como deve ser o livro ["Dicionário Analógico da Língua Portuguesa"](http://www.lexikon.com.br/dicionario_analogico/dicionarioanalogico.html), de Francisco Ferreira dos Santos Azevedo.

O site [Tudo na Língua](http://www.tudonalingua.com/news/dicionariodeideiaseafins/), citando [este post](http://ecos-da-traducao.blogspot.com.br/2012/01/dica-da-semana-dicionario-de-ideias-e.html) do blog Ecos da Tradução, apresenta a seguinte lista de *Sites para Dicionário de Ideias Afins Online*:

- [Dicionário de Semântica/ Dicionário de Ideias](http://www.codeorama.com/semantica/)
- [Pequeno dicionário de ideias afins](http://www.editoraibep.com.br/oficinadeescritores/IdeiasAfins/)
- <s>[Thesaurus da Língua Portuguesa](http://alcor.concordia.ca/%7Evjorge/Thesaurus/) - este é um HTML de 2005, e merece um backup</s>
- [Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/amarelo)

O [thesaurus do site Babylon](http://thesaurus.babylon.com/) tem resultados curiosos, mostrando várias línguas e sites com a definição buscada.

E um PDF acadêmico bem interessante, fica como referência para futuros pesquisadores:

> [**A construção de um Thesaurus eletrônico para o português do Brasil**](http://seer.fclar.unesp.br/alfa/article/view/4244)
> Este trabalho discute o equacionamento lingüístico da construção de um Thesaurus Eletrônico para o Português do Brasil. Na introdução, contextualizamos esse equacionamento no domínio da pesquisa em processamento automático de línguas naturais.

---

O post do Ecos da Tradução nos ensina que há quatro tipos de dicionários: de definição; de sinônimos; etimológico; analógico (de ideias e afins). E no site [Dicionários Online](http://www.dicionarios-online.com/gerais.html) vemos estes sites relevantes, tem uma lista grande de recursos, mas estes são os que vem ao caso:

- [Dicionário de Sinônimos](http://www.sinonimos.com.br/)
- [Dicionário Etimológico Online](http://www.dicionarioetimologico.com.br/)
- [Dicionário inFormal](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/)