# Dicionário de português com regências ("Collocation dictionary")

Tags: recursos-online

Estou procurando **dicionário de português** com **regências verbal e nominal** ("Collocation dictionary"), necessito que seja em **formato digital** de preferência online.

Eu encontrei [Dicionário Prático de Regência Nominal](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8508127642), mas ele é somente disponível em formato impresso.

Exemplo "collocation dictionary" em inglês:

- [Ozdic](http://www.ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/morning)
- [Oxford Dictionary](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=night)

Comment: Anderson, seja bem-vindo.  Sua pergunta foge ao que o site espera dos participantes.  É uma pergunta que pode ter várias respostas e, portanto, é classificada como "pergunta cuja resposta é baseada em opinião", um dos tipos de pergunta proscritos pelo site.

Comment: O Ciberduvidas dá [aqui](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/dicionario-de-regencias-nomes-e-adjectivos/24352) três referências. Parece-me que a tua melhor opção é comprar um deles e digitalizá-lo.

Comment: @Centaurus é uma pergunta bastante aberta; mas não é, de todo, uma "pergunta cuja resposta é baseada em opinião" -> não é subjetivo se algo é um "dicionário de/com regências verbal e nominal (...) digital de preferência online".

Comment: Já existem, que eu saiba, três perguntas pedindo recursos online aqui no site: [esta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/600/dicion%C3%A1rio-anal%C3%B3gico-online?rq=1), [esta outra](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/483/online-portuguese-dictionary-with-ipa-transcriptions) e [mais esta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/tabela-dos-fonemas-com-exemplos-de-sonoridade?lq=1). Eu tenho algumas dúvidas sobre o mérito deste tipo perguntas, mas o que é permitido a uns é permitido a todos.

Comment: @Jacinto se quiseres podes abrir a discussão disso no meta, eu também não sou de acordo com perguntas de recursos principalmente porque normalmente são baseadas em links e ficam desatualizadas facilmente. Mas não vou fechar a pergunta, a comunidade é quem decide.

Comment: No meta existe uma [discussão sobre "perguntas-referência"](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/178/157). Eu gostava que ela tivesse progredido mais, mas parece ter estagnado.

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu estou a par da discussão no meta apontado pelo ANeves. Eu não tenho opinião definida, exceto que o critério tem que ser o mesmo para todos. Como ninguém abriu uma votação para fechar esta pergunta, não vejo necessidade de abrir mais uma discussão no meta sobre isto.

Answer (score 2):

Que eu saiba não há nenhum que satisfaça as tuas condições.

O Ciberduvidas dá [aqui](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/dicionario-de-regencias-nomes-e-adjectivos/24352) três referências. Parece-me que a melhor opção é comprar um deles e digitalizá-lo.

Podes também fazer uma pesquisa num corpus como o [CETEMPúblico](http://www.linguateca.pt/cetempublico/). Por exemplo, para verbos que antecedem noite, possivelmente com um artigo pelo meio, podes pesquisar por `@[pos="V.*"] [pos="DET_art."]{0,1} [lema="noite"]` e escolher "distribuição de lemas". Os primeiros resultados são:

```
passar   725
ser      635
animar   143
acabar   69
haver    54
cair     39
fechar   36
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenho uma sugestão sobre regência verbal. Caso você já tenha estudado os tipos verbais (verbo transitivo direto, verbo transitivo indireto, verbo intransitivo...), Você pode utilizar o [Dicio](http://www.dicio.com.br/) para ver o tipo do verbo e saber a regência dele e como usar.

Por exemplo, o verbo **assistir** ([link](http://www.dicio.com.br/assistir/)):

> **verbo transitivo indireto**. Estar presente
>
> *Exemplo em frase:* Assistir a uma sessão.
>
> **verbo transitivo direto**. Ajudar, acompanhar
>
> *Exemplo em frase:* Ele o assistiu na doença.
>
> **verbo intransitivo**. Residir, morar
>
> *Exemplo em frase:* Ele assiste no Rio de Janeiro